# Bluetooth Adaptor Unable to Detect Headphones

Tags: linux-mint, audio, bluetooth

My computer runs Mint 20.1. I got some new [Bluetooth headphones](https://www.jbl.com/over-ear-headphones/TUNE760NC-.html) and an [USB Bluetooth adapter](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/ub500/). I installed Wine, downloaded the adapter's driver (double-checking the hardware version to make sure it was the right one), and ran the setup.exe file using Wine. The Bluetooth symbol is now on my taskbar and when I click it a small window simply called Bluetooth appears. As far as I can tell, the Bluetooth driver on computer now works.

However, my headphones cannot connect. I can connect the headphones to my phone, so they cannot be the problem. [This](https://www.zdnet.com/article/when-bluetooth-on-linux-fails-this-command-can-come-to-the-rescue-heres-how-to-set-it-up/) article says bluetoothctl can help, but it didn't for me. [This](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=334816) thread mentioned that installing Blueman, but again I saw no change.

I asked this question on the [Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2437360#p2437360), but could they could not help. A user did asked me to run some code in terminal and post the results, but ultimately did not have any solutions. Should I consider buying a new adapter, or does anyone have any possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I installed Wine, downloaded the adapter's driver (double-checking the hardware version to make sure it was the right one), and ran the setup.exe file using Wine.

You don't do that. The vast majority of Windows device drivers do not work under Wine. Wine is a userspace application, it cannot allow Windows drivers to directly access (device mapped) RAM, run ioctls(), etc.

According to `dmesg` your kernel has failed to detect your bluetooth adapter.

According to this https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:2357-0604 you need at the very least kernel 5.14 in order to make it work. Your distro comes with version 5.4. I'd try something newer/fresher, e.g. `Linux Mint v21.3` which comes with kernel 6.5.